# pyrogram как скачать фото с сообщения, на которое был сделан ответ пользователем?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Пытаюсь сделать демотиватор(цитата к фотографии, как в @super_rjaka_demotivator_bot) для юзербота телеграм, но столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно скачать фото с сообщения на которое я сделаю ответ, а я не знаю как :(
помогите решить плиз
либа pyrogram

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а в чём проблема просто прикрепить фото к своему сообщению и прогнать через await app.download_media(message)

Comment: я пытался, ругается текст который должен быть в цитате, он нонтайп изза прикреплённого фото

Answer (score 0):

```
Client.download_media(message, file_name)
```

Подробнее: [download_media()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/download_media)